# Are CME security id's unique and constant over time?

Tags: cme

For any given day, CME security IDs are unique - a number will always refer to a single product.

Are they unique over time as well? That is, might a new security have a security id that used to be used by an expired one?

And are they constant? That is, does a given security keep the same security id over its lifetime?

Comment: I have been looking for this exact questions, as well as how it can be determined which security ID corresponds to which trading instrument e.g. would "743016" be British Pound/Euro Future etc etc. In the MDP 3 spec it doesn't seem to cover this particularly well, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking to CME, apparently they are neither unique nor constant.

The obvious case when a security would change id is if it is a user defined strategy, which got created a second time - identical security, but different id.

But CME does not even commit to not changing security ids of regular instruments, such as futures, although in practice they are unlikely to change (this was my understanding of the answer).

Once a security expires, its id might be reused as well.